# apache storm throws Exception "java.net.BindException: Address already in use"

Tags: apache-storm, binding-expressions

Apache storm throws exception when I submit a new topology in storm cluster which has 100+ free slots. The storm cluster has 35 nodes.

```
org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6734
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Server.<init>(Server.java:101) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Context.bind(Context.java:67) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$worker_data$fn__5173.invoke(worker.clj:272) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$assoc_apply_self.invoke(util.clj:931) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$worker_data.invoke(worker.clj:269) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5471$exec_fn__1371__auto__$reify__5473.run(worker.clj:613) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5471$exec_fn__1371__auto____5472.invoke(worker.clj:611) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5471$mk_worker__5562.doInvoke(worker.clj:585) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:769) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
2019-11-02 18:39
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:372) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:296) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
2019-11-01 17:57:42.487 o.a.s.util main [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error on initialization")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5471$mk_worker__5562.doInvoke(worker.clj:585) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:769) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
```

When I use lsof command to find out which process uses the port, it shows

```
$ lsof -i:6734
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    21812  orc  292u  IPv6 2397383060      0t0  TCP bj4191:6734->10.15.70.5:boe-resssvr2 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30636  orc   58u  IPv6 2394755694      0t0  TCP bj4191:28367->10.12.178.13:6734 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30636  orc   90u  IPv6 2394760492      0t0  TCP bj4191:23217->10.12.174.3:6734 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30636  orc 1191u  IPv6 2397398591      0t0  TCP bj4191:6734->10.12.172.46:6307 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30645  orc   88u  IPv6 2394657692      0t0  TCP bj4191:22997->10.12.174.3:6734 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30645  orc   99u  IPv6 2394657702      0t0  TCP bj4191:28257->10.12.178.13:6734 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30645  orc 3016u  IPv6 2394770505      0t0  TCP bj4191:6734->10.32.210.18:boks_clntd (ESTABLISHED)
```

I can't understand why the second process use an address which has been used. How can I solve it? Thx.

Comment: Consider upgrading to a newer version. 1.0.3 is pretty old. Maybe the issue has been fixed? If not, you can submit an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa, but please try the latest Storm version first.

Comment: yes, ports that configed in storm.yaml file, but these ports are free in os, so other application can use these resource also.  When storm want to use the port that was used by other application, it fail.

Comment: Are you saying that another application is using the port, and that's why it's failing? You need to choose a port range for workers that other applications don't use.

Comment: storm topology application use the port